# Twilio Nested Gather Statements Not Working

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to have Twilio dial a number and then listen for voice commands from the user and then speak some text to the user and then keep waiting for more voice commands from the user. I want this to run non-stop until the user disconnects. Instead it works once - the user speaks and it calls the action URL on my server as part of the gather and then it speaks and then disconnects.

In the action URL I specified I'm having my server return a TwiML which contains another Gather statement to have the process keep repeating, however the Gather statement inside the action URL is being ignored.

Initially the following TwiML is being returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>

<Say>Hello 0</Say>

<Gather input='speech' action='https://0fc2-**-**-**-14.ngrok-free.app/test/gather2' speechTimeout='auto' speechModel='phone_call' enhanced='true'></Gather>

<Say>After Gather</Say>

</Response>
```

Here it says "Hello 0" and then calls my webhook endpoint at https://0fc2-**-**-***-14.ngrok-free.app/test/gather2 which has the text of what the user spoke. It does not say "After Gather" since it went to the gather statement.

Now in the gather2 endpoint it returns the following TwiML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>

<Say>Hello 2</Say>

<Gather input='speech' action='https://0fc2-***-**-***-14.ngrok-free.app/test/repeat' speechTimeout='10' speechModel='phone_call' enhanced='true'></Gather>

<Say>After Gather 2</Say>

</Response>
```

It says "Hello2" and then it says "After Gather2" and it never calls the /test/repeat endpoint even thought the user is speaking.

How do I resolve this?

Using nested gather statements which doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are describing is by design. For Gather, upon successful gather of digits or speech, the action URL takes over the responsibility for issuing Twiml and anything after the action URL will not be reached. This is explained in the documentation for [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action):

> After  ends and Twilio sends its request to your action URL,
> the current call will continue using the TwiML you send back from that
> URL. **Because of this, any TwiML verbs that occur after your 
> are unreachable.**
> However, if the caller did not enter any digits or speech, call flow
> would continue in the original TwiML document.

Try not pressing any buttons or saying anything, wait for the 10 seconds of the speechTimeout to expire, and you should hear the "After Gather" message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was missing produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE on my REST endpoint which is accepting the webhook. Once I've added it then it was correctly picking up the GATHER tag.